# Design patterns for data transfer in an FPGA

Tags: vhdl, hardware, fpga

This is more of a general question about FPGA design than a specific question about code. I studied computer science but have been trying to learn more about hardware recently. I’ve been using a Xilinx FPGA to teach myself VHDL and some of the basics about hardware design, but I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge that have led to me hitting some pretty big walls in my projects. This is the most recent one.

I have a design with a couple dozen “workers”. Part of the design’s functionality depends on these workers executing compute-heavy tasks. In order to save FPGA resources, I have the workers sharing the computing circuitry and have another module to schedule access to that circuitry between the workers. The logic itself works fine and I’ve tested it in the simulator, however when I try to implement the design on the FPGA itself it never meets the timing requirements. A look at the diagram in Vivado showed me that the placer puts all of the shared computing circuitry on one side of the FPGA and all of the workers on the other side. Additionally, the routes that carry data from the workers to the computing circuitry meet timing but the routes that carry the results back to the workers are almost all failing.

So, my question is what solutions are typically used to fix data transfer problems like this in hardware design? I know that I could lower the clock rate to give the signals more time to move around, but I’m hesitant to do that since it would decrease the overall throughout of my design. On the other hand, I could place a few buffers between the shared computing circuitry and the workers (acting like a shift register), at the cost of increasing the compute time for the individual workers. What other techniques or design patterns are there for moving data around between points in an FPGA that are far apart?

Comment: You don't appear to be describing a programming problem and you don't provide enough detail to recommend an architecture solution.

Comment: I suspect that your fundamental problem is that you're trying to turn a software paradigm (multithreaded, workers) into hardware. We don't do it that way, and we don't do 'design patterns' (that a programmer would understand, anyway). Rule #1: think hardware; registers, dataflow, simple function units, etc. Your specific question on moving data between far-apart points on a chip is very specialised and unlikely to be your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the solutions you propose to reduce timing violations are rights and the most common.

You can also :

- Modify synthesis and implementation directives in Vivado to prefer **timing optimization** than **ressources utilization** or **compute time** (of the synthesis and implementation).
- Rework your compute unit to ensure that there is a buffer after all of your logic. Indeed you have different ways to segment your compute unit between sequential part and combinationnal part.
- Place and route critical parts of your design by yourself. I never did it but I know it's possible (at least set location constraints in *.xdc*).

About adding buffers on the critcial paths : if you can do a piplined architecture, you will only add one latency clock cycle (It's not a high cost to ensure your design will work correctly).